# Слово "матрешка"

Tags: орфография, морфология

Какое проверочное слово у слова "матрешка"?

Answer (score 2):

Название этой игрушки восходит к женскому имени Матрёна.

Матрёна — форма вместо более старой (Матрона).

Матрона — почтенная замужняя женщина, мать семейства у древних римлян (от mater - мать).

Значит, проверочное слово — мать.

Comment: А  если - Мотря.  Шучу,  конечно.  Но  лучше  просто  запомнить.